# error: identifier "list" is undefined (new to Visual C++)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I just want to initialize a List on Visual C++ but I am getting following errors:

- error: identifier "list" is undefined
- error C2065: 'list' : undeclared identifier

why is this happening?

my includes:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <WebServices.h>
#include "./WCF_managed_app.xsd.h"
#include "./WCF_managed_app_Client.wsdl.h"
#include "./WCF_managed_app_Client.xsd.h"
#include "./schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd.h"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you probably have forgotten the `using namespace std;` in your cpp file so as to have access to the definition of `list` that resides into the `std` namespace.

personnaly I prefer not to use `using namespace std;`

and I use `std::list` rather of `list` in my cpp files

```
std::list<Element> myList;
myList.push_back(anElement);
```